# Codeigniter - throw exception if database transaction fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I am trying catch database errors within a transaction and if one occurs then rollback and throw an exception.

However, the code is stopping and displaying the db error screen before it throws the exception.

Any ideas how I can make it detect db error without stopping running the subsequent code?

```
try {
    $this->my_function($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

---

```
private function my_function($data)
{

    $this->db->trans_start();
    foreach($data as $reg)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $reg);
        if($this->db->query($sql))
        {
            continue;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            throw new Exception('Exception message here...');
        }
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();

}
```

Comment: what is the error displaying on screen before it throws the exception.?

Comment: I've purposely mis-spelt a column name to create an error

Comment: it is expected behavior. error display immediately when it occurs. if condition execute after that

Comment: So is there any way to produce the results I want?

Comment: you should [handle exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in order to control error messages.but codeigniter provide better way to do this see `trans_status()` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html.but still error will display if you don't handle it

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I "handle the error"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125404/discussion-between-tom-and-fast-snail).

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600125/check-codeigniter-query-errors-instead-of-showing-them-to-the-user) question

As answered by cwallenpoole:

In application/config/database.php set

```
// suppress error output to the screen
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

In your model or controller:

```
// try the select.
$dbRet = $this->db->select($table, $dataArray);
// select has had some problem.
if( !$dbRet )
{
   $errNo   = $this->db->_error_number()
   $errMess = $this->db->_error_message();
   // Do something with the error message or just show_404();
}
```

Or in you case:

```
private function my_function($data)
{
    $errors = array();
    $this->db->trans_start();
    foreach($data as $reg)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $reg);
        if($this->db->query($sql))
        {
            continue;
        } else {
            $errNo   = $this->db->_error_number()
            $errMess = $this->db->_error_message();
            array_push($errors, array($errNo, $errMess));
        }
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    // use $errors...
}
```

**Even better**

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168886/codeigniter-error-tracking-in-transaction) has all the answers you need because it takes multiple inserts into account and let's you finish the once that did not return an error.